# Daterangepicker bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, daterangepicker

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в ***Daterangepicker bootstrap*** добавить русскую локализацию?
Я пробовал делать так:
Во втором примере сработало только на месяцы, а дни недели остались на английском. Все остальные попытки результатов не дали.

```
$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    locale: 'ru'
});

$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    locale: {
        closeText: 'Закрыть',
        prevText: '<Пред',
        nextText: 'След>',
        currentText: 'Сегодня',
        monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн','Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
        dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
        dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
        weekHeader: 'Нед',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        numberOfMonths: 2
    }
});

$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    datepickerOptions: {
        closeText: 'Закрыть',
        prevText: '<Пред',
        nextText: 'След>',
        currentText: 'Сегодня',
        monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн','Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
        dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
        dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
        weekHeader: 'Нед',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: '',
        numberOfMonths: 2
    }
});


$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    daterangepickerOptions: {
    closeText: 'Закрыть',
    prevText: '<Пред',
    nextText: 'След>',
    currentText: 'Сегодня',
    monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн','Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
    dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
    dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
    weekHeader: 'Нед',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    numberOfMonths: 2
  }
});

$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    closeText: 'Закрыть',
    prevText: '<Пред',
    nextText: 'След>',
    currentText: 'Сегодня',
    monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Янв','Фев','Мар','Апр','Май','Июн','Июл','Авг','Сен','Окт','Ноя','Дек'],
    dayNames: ['воскресенье','понедельник','вторник','среда','четверг','пятница','суббота'],
    dayNamesShort: ['вск','пнд','втр','срд','чтв','птн','сбт'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
    weekHeader: 'Нед',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: '',
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена:

```
$('#daterangepicker').daterangepicker({
  locale: {
    monthNames: ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
    daysOfWeek: ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'],
    firstDay: 1,
  },
});
```